# How do I prevent "I attack with Fight" and "I attack with Shoot"-type brief declarations?

Tags: fate, fate-core

One thing I like about FAE is that attacks and defenses have to go beyond "I attack them with Fight."/"I defend with Fight." to justify using an approach or the other. Merely providing an adverb adds to the story.

The problem with Fate Core's Fight and Shoot, I feel, is the same as D&D's. No declarations beyond the "push button to attack" are necessary, and it feels dry unless there's incentive on the players to go further, and since my players are new (and a D&D session failed partially because of the lack of descriptive incentive) I need help with boring, brief declarations like the ones in the title in Fate Core.

Comment: Instead to leave them to choose which skill they want to use,  ask them HOW they'll do things, and them choose the more appropriate skill